# How do I get Firefox tabs really on top?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Firefox 4 has a tabs on top feature, but it doesn't really work if you have customized toolbar.

For example:
I've got all my navigation buttons and address and search fields on the file "Menu Bar" toolbar, When you select "Tabs on top", the tabs move above the bookmark toolbar, which is pointless. It looks like this:

```
navigation, address, search, menu
tabs toolbar
bookmarks toolbar
```

I'd prefer something like this:

```
bookmarks toolbar
tabs toolbar
navigation, address, search, menu
```

Comment: which OS? + 15 char

Comment: windoze XP. Of course I'd like this to work at home as well... linux

Comment: I'm confused: isn't the whole point of tabs-on-top to move the tabs bars above everything else and integrate into the title bar? Having the bookmarks bar above the tabs bar when in tabs-on-top mode would defeat the purpose of tabs-on-top.

Comment: @AniDev - Not everyone has the same needs as you, therefore not everyone has the same purpose behind their actions. The reason I want to do that is because the tabs do not move on top with my toolbar layout. Try it: put all the buttons on the menu bar. Then do tabs-on-top. Not cool.

Comment: BTW, firefox tabs on top does not move the tabs to the title bar like Chrome - at least on XP and FF BETA 7 it doesn't

Comment: I now see what you mean. How well does it look if you put everything on the navigation bar, remove the menu bar, and activate tabs-on-top? Removing the menu bar will the tabs the highest thing visible and add the Firefox menu button, which should integrate into the title bar.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Were is the firefox menu button? I think that could be a solution as I need the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on any bar, then in the context menu you need to unmark the Menu Bar.

This step is crucial as it moves the Menu Bar out of the way, because it's a top-most bar by default.

Comment: If you read the question, you'd see that what you are saying means I will have only tabs. ALL my controls are on the menu bar: back, forward, URL, search, menu. If you hide that, you're screwed. I've put everything on the menu bar because it is the top-most bar. But I want the tabs to be the top-most bar. The only two things that you can't move wherever you like are: menu and tabs.

Comment: Obvious solution: Take that all off of the menu bar.

Comment: the menu bar is a requirement. I need a menu.

Comment: That's what the FIREFOX button is. You could consider the Compact Menu addon, which replaces the menu bar with a menu button, but firefox 4 has the firefox button for that.

Comment: Unfortunately FF7 Linux version has no FIREFOX button that I am aware of. Where do I find this button?

Comment: I use FF7 on linux, it's the word FIREFOX in the top left corner. Even with window decorations hidden, it should be there. http://i.imgur.com/3i4ZV.png

Comment: What I had to do was, put everything on the tab bar and then hide the menu. When this is done, then the FIREFOX button appears, with just about all the menu items I need. Thanks!

Comment: If you install Compact Menu 2, it'll add "MENU" to the firefox button, which has the standard menu layout in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13091/) firefox Addon called "Tabs on Top".  If that doesn't do the trick, there are tons of other similar addons that may give you the look that you want.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Unfortunately, it's not available for FF4. FF4 has tabs on top, but not really.

Comment: I use "Tabs on Top" + "Hide Caption Titlebar Plus" add-ons for FF3.6. So FF3.6 now is so like FF4 and I can use a lot of add-ons that are not compatible with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to moving the tabs on top without hacking Firefox would be to change the menubar to a single Firefox button and allow the tabs to be on the top row. The problem is, Firefox still uses the Windows frame around it whereas Google Chrome doesn't and I'm guessing that makes the menu bar only allowed at the very top.

Answer (score 0):

I could not perform your "requirements" for toolbar positions, but you can do that with FF4: place bookmarks toolbar between Firefox orange ribbon and the tabs. Just press mouse right button on a toolbar and press "customize" option. Then drag and drop the bookmarks toolbar to where do you want and then ok.

But tabs on top for FF4 is only for when the window is maximized. So use "Hide Caption Titlebar Plus" add-on to make the titlebar disappears also for restored windows :) Then adjust something settings to do it better for you.